# Docker multi-stage build fails if we use CMD in dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8 as builder
# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/mymaven
COPY ./ /usr/src/mymaven
CMD [ "mvn" , "clean" , "install" ]

FROM openjdk:8
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/mymaven/target /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD ["java", "-jar" , "Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

The above docker build fails with the error:
target folder does not exist
The below dockerfile works perfectly:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8 as builder
# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/mymaven
COPY ./ /usr/src/mymaven
RUN [ "mvn" , "clean" , "install" ]

FROM openjdk:8
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/mymaven/target /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD ["java", "-jar" , "Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Just changing CMD to RUN fixed the issue. Why is this happening? I thought in the intermittent container, the cmd would execute which should make both the commands equivalent right?

Comment: `CMD` does not run anything at build-time. It just sets a default command when you run the container later.

Comment: "I thought in the intermittent container, the cmd would execute which should make both the commands equivalent right" Do you have any links where it says that?

Comment: @Thilo no sources just my assumption

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a multistage build, you may copy files from a previous step. Each step is considered as an individual, private **image**(in the scope of the multistage build).

`CMD` instruction however is not invoked at build time, it only applies at runtime as clearly stated in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an **executing
> container**.

Since you are currently building the result image, `CMD` is never executed thus you get the error you have reported.

In the other hand, `RUN` instruction executes during build time making its result available for the next step. Quoting again from [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> **The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of
> the current image and commit the results**. The resulting committed
> image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

It should be clear by now why the multistage build completes successfully when `RUN` is used in contrast to `CMD` instruction.

Your confusion started from wrongly assuming that the below is true:

> I thought in the intermittent container, the cmd would execute which should make both the commands equivalent right?